# Can't bind an Activity to Service

Tags: android, android-intent, bind, android-service

I'm having trouble getting the onServiceConnected() method to run, which means that it's not binding my activity to the service.

It's probably something simple that I've missed out - but I've tried quite a few times - starting from scratch.

Here we go...

**My Service Class**

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;

public class QuickService extends Service {

private final IBinder mBinder = new QuickBinder(this);

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return mBinder;
}

}
```

**My Binder Class**

```
import android.os.Binder;

public class QuickBinder extends Binder {

private final QuickService service;

public QuickBinder(QuickService service){
    this.service = service;
}

public QuickService getService(){
    return service;
}

}
```

**And... The Activity trying to bind to the service.**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.ServiceConnection;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;

public class QuickActivity extends Activity {

QuickService mService;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_connecting);
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, QuickService.class);
    bindService(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    // Unbind from the service
        unbindService(mConnection);
    }

/** Defines callbacks for service binding, passed to bindService() */
private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className,
            IBinder service) {
        Logger.d("Connected!!! :D");
        // We've bound to LocalService, cast the IBinder and get LocalService instance
        QuickBinder binder = (QuickBinder) service;
        mService = binder.getService();
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
    }
};
}
```

Also, the Service defined in the manifest file - in case you thought that was the problem.

```
<service android:name=".QuickService"></service>
```

So, What am I doing wrong here? Why isn't the onServiceConnected() method being called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update it with following

```
 <service android:name=".QuickService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name=".QuickService .BIND" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

Comment: Thanks, it' all working now. I'll have to go and see why you need to add that now.

Comment: Can you explain why I needed to add that?

Answer (score -1):

Instead of writing:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, QuickService.class);
    bindService(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

You can write:

```
startService(new Intent(QuickActivity.this, QuickService.class));
```

where you want to start service.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Yes, but if I want to have a service that you can bind to, then I don't think that really helps here.